# filter data in Kendo grid by connect to a method asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am making a code using ASP.NET MVC with kendo grid. 
I want to bring the data from database to Kendo grid which equal to specific date or by default "today".

I want to make a datepicker and a button at the toolbar and everytime I click the button it send a request to the control and filter the data in LINQ and send the request for all the data in one day. I wrote this code:

Controller class:

```
//main method
public ActionResult LogAdminList()
        {
            return View();
        }
//submethod for grid
    public ActionResult Grid_ReadLogAdminList([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "id")] string date)
            {
                DateTime _temp;
                if (!DateTime.TryParse(date, out _temp))
                    _temp = DateTime.Now;

                return Json(_context.Entities<LogAdmin>().NoTracking().OrderByDescending(l => l.TimeStamp)
                    .Where(f => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(f.TimeStamp) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(_temp))
                    .Select(l => new LogAdminInfo
                    {
                        Id = l.Id,
                        Message = l.Message,
                        MessageTemplate = l.MessageTemplate,
                        Level = l.Level,
                        TimeStamp = l.TimeStamp,
                        Exception = l.Exception,
                        Properties = l.Properties,
                        LogEvent = l.LogEvent,
                    })
                    .ToDataSourceResult(request));
            }
```

the kendo code is :

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<LogAdminInfo>()
        .BindTo(Model)
        .Name("LogAdminList")
        .Sortable()
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.Message).Width(50).Title(WebResources.LogListMessage);
            columns.Bound(p => p.MessageTemplate).Width(50).Title(WebResources.LogListMessageTemplate);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Level).Title(WebResources.LogListLevel);
            columns.Bound(p => p.TimeStamp).Title(WebResources.LogListTimeStamp).Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy H:mm}");
            columns.Bound(p => p.Exception).Width(50).Title(WebResources.LogListException);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Properties).Width(50).Title(WebResources.LogListProperties);
            columns.Bound(p => p.LogEvent).Title(WebResources.LogListLogEvent);
        })
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .ButtonCount(5))
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "grd_UpcomingMilestone" })
            .ToolBar(toolbar =>
                {
                    toolbar.Template(@<text>
                    <div class="toolbar">
                        <label class="category-label" for="category">@WebResources.LogFilterMessage</label>
                        @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
                                        .Name("datepicker")
                                        .Value(DateTime.Today)
                                        .Format("dd.MM.yyyy")
                                        )

                        @(Html.Kendo().Button()
                                        .Name("filterButton")
                                        .Icon("filter")
                                        .Content("Filter")
                                        .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button" })

                        )
                    </div>
                    </text>);
                        })

        .DataSource(source => source
            .Ajax()
            .Batch(true)
            .ServerOperation(false)
            .PageSize(100)
            .Read(read => read.Action("Grid_ReadLogAdminList", "LogAdmin").Data("getFilterDate"))
        ))
```

I don't know what to do exactly in the javascript. the code works fine in the first request but not when I filter.

what should I write as a javascript?

thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass data from client to server using `getFilterDate` function specified in you Kendo Grid Read `Data` method. Implement a function like this. The return type must be an object with fields with the same name you defined in your MVC Action, in this case `date`. Kendo will serialize them in order to build the get request:

```
function getFilterDate() {
    var mydate = $("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker").value();
    return {
       "date": mydate
    }
}
```